# Error: 'XXXX' is not a member of 'YYYY'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a website with about 20 pages, created in Visual Studio 2013.

I've created a class called users which is in the App_Code folder.

I'm consuming the class in various pages, however I'm getting intermittent errors on only one page (UserMaintenance.aspx.vb).

The errors in the Error Lists are:

```
Error 101 'management_seq' is not a member of 'users'.  
Error 102 'cash_seq' is not a member of 'users'.
etc...
```

These attributes certainly are members of the users class. (See below.)

Looking at the page, there are no errors. 
What I don't understand at all, is when I double click the error in the Error List, it doesn't take me to the actual page, rather to the following location:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\website--1538976792\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\live\UserMaintenance.aspx.vb
```

The class is:

```
Public Class Users

    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property isAdmin As Boolean
    Public Property isActive As Boolean
    Public Property management_seq As String
    Public Property cash_seq As String
    Public Property stock_seq As String
    Public Property customers_seq As String
    Public Property suppliers_seq As String
    Public Property graphs_seq As String
    Public Property additional_seq As String
    Public Property branches_list As List(Of Branches)

End Class

Public Class Branches

   Public Property BranchCode

End Class
```

I'm getting an "error" on the 2nd line on the code below:

```
Private Sub SelectPermissions(ByVal _user As Users)
    Dim management_string As String = _user.management_seq
End Sub
```

I'm completely baffled :)

Comment: It seems that the passing object is not instantiated. How do you call `SelectPermissions()`

Comment: @un-lucky Dim _user As New Users
_user = _DLayer.GetUserDetails(cboUsers.Text)
SelectPermissions(_user)

Comment: Put break point on ` Dim management_string As String = _user.management_seq` and hover over `_user`, what kind of object it there? Is this expected type or different type?

Comment: It shows the correct object, Users.

Comment: And if you peek into object, do you see the property in it?

Comment: Yep, it it opens the object. I just noticed that I have a page called users.aspx in the site. I'm wondering if that may be causing some issues.

Comment: This is possible. Try fully qualify namespace

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of trying different things, I noticed that there was a webpage, users.aspx (It was an old page that was no longer being used.)

After deleting the page, the project built and published without any errors.

I'm assuming that there was some type of conflict between the users webpage and the users class. Why it only happened in one of the pages that consumed that class, I'm not certain.